Kernel Panic When trying to boot the iso to install ubuntu on wds with syslinux
I installed syslinux WDS system so i can install both a pre-made image of windows 10 and ubuntu 23.10 over the network with PXE boot, currently I am testing ubuntu so the iso is vanilla, but when I try too boot into the live environment it Kernel Panics with this error :  Kernel panic - not syncing: VFS: Unable to mount root fs on unknown-block(2,0)
Is there any way to fix this problem, am i missing something ??
Any help will be appreciated
If anyone needs more info just ask.
